# In $\mathbb C$ does $\sqrt z=z^{1/2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

First of all, is $z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$ really a function? Indeed, each complex number has two square roots, so I have the impression that $\sqrt z$ is not well-defined as a function, is it? Then, I was wondering if $\sqrt z=z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ was still true. Indeed, $z^{1/2}:=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log(z)}$, and this is holomorphic in some domain. Whereas, I even have doubt if $z\mapsto \sqrt z$ is really a function. What do you think ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notations $\sqrt{z}$ and $z^{1/2}$ both refer to the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) of $z$, which is defined as the solution of $w^2=z$ with argument in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Using $\log(z)$ you run into the same problem because $\exp(w)=z$ even has infinitely many solutions $w\in\Bbb C$. This is why for complex numbers you would write $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ to refer to the [principal value of the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value), which is the solution of $\exp(w)=z$ with imaginary part in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Note that the two choices of principal branches agree so that indeed
$$
\sqrt{z} = \exp\left(\frac12 \operatorname{Log}(z)\right) = z^{1/2}.
$$